# Is it possible to edit TV-params of child resources while editing parent resource?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Is it possible to edit TV-params of child resources while editing parent resource in backend?
So I want to output all published child resources of News category in backend as dropdown select. And I want to edit TV-params of this child resouces.
[image]

Comment: "Software recommendations" are off topic for this site. As such I have removed where you asked for plugins that could do this in hopes to make your question more objective.

Comment: @CaptainMan plugin in Modx CMS is not a software. It is just a php-code

Comment: If you believe my edit to be in error you can revert it. I see many questions people flag for that and it is annoying that they do this because usually it is just one small sentence saying something like "if X cannot do it, can someone suggest a thing to do it". So to help the questions like yours stay open I edit out those bits so people won't try to close them as being recommendation questions. I did not vote to close, I just took out that sentence in hopes that other people wouldn't see it as an excuse to close the question.